# How to store a geojson file in a parquet format?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geojson, parquet, fastparquet

I have a large geojson file which I save as follows:

```
 geomap.to_file(path_to_output + 'geomap_cleaned.geojson', driver="GeoJSON")
```

then i read the same file as:

```
geomap = import_geojson(path_to_data, path_to_cadgis, 'geomap_cleaned.geojson')
```

My issue is that `geomap` is a large file (1G) and the kernel in my jupyter notebook crashes most of time when I try to read it.

I made an attempt to save the geojson file in a parquet format

```
geomap.to_parquet(path_to_data + 'geomap_cleaned.gzip', compression='GZIP', engine='pyarrow')
```

but  i get an error.

```
ArrowInvalid: Cannot parse URI: './Source data/geomap.gzip'
```

How can I solve this problem ? and how can I make sure the geometries, when stored in parquet format, are not corrupted?

Thank you